# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams without LayoutParams usage

Tags: android

I use a view which has RelativeLayout -> ScrollView -> LinearLayout. I get exception:

```
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3131)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:805)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-22 11:17:24.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5161):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why does it happen only occassionally? Why is there no detail of where the code failed?

Update: I suspect it should fail around this code:

```
EditText input = new EditText(context);
input.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

LayoutParams is RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: please post the code of your adapter

Comment: Well, show us xml and java code. How do you expect us to solve this without them?

Comment: we don't care what you do suspect :) give us a larger portion of your code

Comment: added snippet for the code that I believe is causing trouble.

Comment: see, the point is that if you think that the problem is there you would probably be smart enough to fix that on your own. But the problem might have roots way before in your code. At least, post the whole method where that snippet is. Since you can't fix the problem on your own where you think you found it, it'll be probably elsewhere.

Comment: This line is also interesting: `EditText input = new EditText(context);` It seems the code creates views dynamically? Then we should definitely need to see more code. We cannot be sure views are added/created as per the given layout hierarchy. I'm sorry but we cannot help further without more code to see. I hope the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` solved the issues.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(...)` instead of `new LayoutParams(...)`

You always need to use the parent layout's class for the `LayoutParams`. E.g. if `EditText` is inside `FrameLayout` then `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` must be used.

Comment: Relative > scrollView > LinearLayout > EditText